# multiple routes in single Route::get() call Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When defining a route in Laravel 4 is it possible to define multiple URI paths within the same route?

presently i do the following:

```
Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');
Route::get('/dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'v1\DashboardController@index'));
```

but this defeats my purpose, i would like to do something like

```
Route::get('/, /dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
```

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer to redirect `/` to `/dashboard` (or vice-versa) for SEO and simplicity purposes, why have two urls that display the exact same content ?

Comment: @Alexandre Danault In some cases, you'd want to (slightly) vary the content of your view based on the route, yet at the same time, handle requests with a single controller (i.e. not to repeat the entire logic in 3 different controller methods).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question right I'd say:

Use **Route Prefixing**: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing

Or **(Optional) Route Parameters**: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

So for example:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/'), function() { Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@index'); });
```

OR

```
Route::get('/{dashboard?}', array('as' => 'dashboard', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'));
```

Comment: The second example will match any uri e.g. `/foo`  this answer is wrong

Comment: Thank you so much.
As in my case one of the routes, passing an empty parameter, was sending me to another route with the same prefix. I was already starting to check on the second route if the parameter was the suffix of the initial route I wanted, and redirect ... But the optional argument saved me and now the execution enters the correct route ...

Answer (score 26):

I believe you need to use an optional parameter with a regular expression:

```
Route::get('/{name}', array(
     'as' => 'dashboard', 
     'uses' => 'DashboardController@index')
    )->where('name', '(dashboard)?');
```

*** Assuming you want to route to the same controller which is not entirely clear from the question.

*** The current accepted answer matches everything not just `/` OR `/dashboard`.

Comment: 2 years after, this question is still relevant. Is it possible however to handle the case with more than two routes? Ex: same controller to '/', '/dashboard', and '/home'? Can we further limit the optional parameter to 'home' as well as 'dashboard'?

Comment: @Alex question is relevant. is there any solution so far?

Answer (score 22):

I find it interesting for curiosity sake to attempt to solve this [question posted by @Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489492/multiple-routes-in-single-routeget-call-laravel-4/45588385#comment64931280_21970797) as a comment [under @graemec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970797/5704410)'s answer to post a solution that works:

```
Route::get('/{name}', [
    'as' => 'dashboard', 
    'uses' => 'DashboardController@index'
  ]
)->where('name', 'home|dashboard|'); //add as many as possible separated by |
```

Because the second argument of `where()` expects regular expressions so we can assign it to match *exactly* any of those separated by `|` so my initial thought of proposing a `whereIn()` into Laravel route is resolved by this solution.

> PS:This example is tested on Laravel 5.4.30

Hope someone finds it useful