# How to group multiple routes with the same controller method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following in my `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('test/foo', 'TestController@index');

Route::get('test/bar', 'TestController@index');

Route::get('test/baz', 'TestController@index');
```

and I am trying to reduce this to the following:

```
Route::get(either 'test/foo' or 'test/bar' or 'test/baz', 'TestController@index');
```

One [documented approach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) that would sort of apply here, is to place a regex constraint to the route:

```
Route::get('test/{uri}','TestController@index')->where('uri', 'regex for foo, bar, and baz...');
```

However, this solution would be ugly. Isn't there an elegant way to just express

```
{uri} in foo,bar,baz
```

in Laravel's language? Otherwise, what would the regex look like?

Thanks!

**P.S.** I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489492/multiple-routes-in-single-routeget-call-laravel-4/21970797#answer-21970797), but it didn't apply to my case with 3 routes.

Comment: Very simple question here, I don't see why the solution is not documented.

Comment: If you believe it should be documented (better or at all) nothing stopping you from submitting a pull request :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you say that RegEx is ugly. I basically think RegEx is one of the most powerful tools.

In your case, I think the below snippet should do the job:

`Route::get('user/{name}', function ($name) { // }) ->where('name', '(foo|bar|baz)');`

The `(foo|bar|baz)` RegExr will match any of these string: 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'. So, if you need more, just add pipe (`|`) and add the needed string.

Comment: It should, @Alex. As in your question, you want this: `Route::get(either 'test/foo' or 'test/bar' or 'test/baz', 'TestController@index');`. So, if you want to match a wildcard here, you will need to add another entry in your route.php after the above snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that!

Comment: Hi @haitran sir, how can I redirect from a post route to one of the get route. I tried to name the get route and then `return redirect()->route('foo');` from post route. But I gives "NotFoundHttpException HTTP 404 Not Found" error in Lumen.