# Laravel 5.x route specific paths into single route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to map both `/tasks` and `/tasks/create` into a single route.

[Currently the following works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970797):

```
Route::get('/tasks', 'TaskController@getAll');
Route::get('/tasks/{url}', 'TaskController@getAll')
    ->where('url', '(create)?');
```

But there is a code duplication that I want to avoid.

The following works but also maps to `/` which I want to exclude:

```
Route::get('{url}', 'TaskController@getAll')
    ->where('url', '(tasks|tasks/create)?');
```

Is there a way to only map those two paths without `/`?

Comment: Why not `Route::get('/tasks/{url?}', "TaskController@getAll")->where("url",'create');` ?

Comment: @apokryfos with your suggestion, `/tasks/create` works but `/tasks` returns 404.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the routes `tasks/` and `tasks/create` you could just do:

```
Route::get('/tasks', 'TaskController@getAll');
Route::get('/tasks/create', 'TaskController@getAll');
```

Hope this helps!