# Laravel 5.2 Routing with optional params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a simple product search engine in Laravel 5.2. I can use either get or post, whichever can accomplish what I'm wanting, even if I need to do some backend processing then pass the pretty URL to another method to show the products.

My parameters are 
 - query
 - merchant
 - brand
 - page
 - sort

All of these parameters can be used on their own or separately. 
I'm wanting to use pretty URLs if at all possible.

Basically I want the URLs to look something like this:

```
/shop/query/shoes
/shop/query/shoes/brand/nike
/shop/query/sort/price
/shop/merchant/amazon
```

There can be many different routes formed by these 5 parameters, but they are all optional. So what is the best solution to making this route work how I'm wanting, without coding for every single possible route.

I'm sure I am overlooking something. I've used Zend Framework before and just use a * after shop and then I can pass anything in regardless.

If you need any other information, let me know. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489492/multiple-routes-in-single-routeget-call-laravel-4

Comment: Look at [Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) and [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Comment: ljubadr, I had earlier, just not quite the solution, unless I make it something like /shop/{query?}/{merchant?}/{brand?}/{sort?}/{page?}, but I was thinking about having the param name prior (/shop/query/{query?}...), and that's where the issue is arising.

Comment: @BFreitag04 I'll post the answer.

Comment: @BFreitag04 I've posted the answer, take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Route::get('shop/{params?}', function(Request $request, $params = '') {
    // everything after "shop/" will be in $params

    // you need to add custom logic to parse and handle $params string

    return $params;

})->where('params', '(([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\/?)+');
```

**{params?}** is [Optional Parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

> Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a ? mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value

***->where('params', ...)*** is [Regular Expression Constraint](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

> You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where method on a route instance. The where method accepts the name of the parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should be constrained

---

**NOTE**

Make sure that you tweak **(([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?)+** regular expression to cover all of your cases, as this is something that I added to quickly test your examples

Comment: This covers the case **even if I need to do some backend processing** :)

Comment: Perfect, I can take it from there, was so close too, I have thrown in {params?} after shop but just never paired that with the regex. Thank you!

Comment: @BFreitag04 Laravel documentation is huge, it's easy to miss things. Good luck! Also, if you ever decide to add (override) route that will cover for example **/shop/query/shoes** just make sure that you **add it before** route from my example. If you add it after, it won't work