# Multiple routes for the same controller function

Tags: laravel, controller, routes, laravel-6

I need to have 2 routes managed by the same controller function.

Instead of creating to different rules, I would like to create 1 rule.
So instead of something like this:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'MyController@index']);
Route::get('dashboard', ['uses' => 'MyController@index']);
```

I want to use 1 rule. I found out this [multiple routes in single Route::get() call Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489492/multiple-routes-in-single-routeget-call-laravel-4) but that code not works for me.

This is what I tried without success:

```
// THEY BOTH DO NOT WORK
Route::get('/{name}', ['uses' => 'MyController@index'])->where('name', 'dashboard|');
Route::get('/{name}', ['uses' => 'MyController@index'])->where('name', '(dashboard)?');
```

With these rules, if I go to `/` route I get 404 error.
If I go to `dashboard` route it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making `name` a [optional route parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-optional-parameters) should work:

```
Route::get('/{name?}', ['uses' => 'MyController@index'])->where('name', 'dashboard');
```

Not sure why you are using `uses`, the shorter version would be:

```
Route::get('/{name?}', 'MyController@index')->where('name', 'dashboard');
```